# Mute sound on lock screen in macOS

Tags: macos

Problem is that colleague at work has iMac. We do group Skype calls but when he is not in office, the Skype keeps ringing untill it's hanged up by timeout. Is there a way how to mute it from lock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS Mojave and Skype 8.39, incoming call notifications are muted if the speaker is muted. If the keyboard does not have a mute button, connecting a PC keyboard that has multimedia buttons and pressing the mute button there works equally well. Note that you sometimes need to change from the lock screen to the user switcher before you get any feedback that the sound is actually muted.

Update: Just tried again with macOS Catalina (10.15.6) and a PC keyboard connected via USB: turning on mute for the computer while on the lock screen still worked (though with no visual feedback that mute was turned on). Changing from the lock screen to the "switch user" screen also enabled the visual notification:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Using a Mac keyboard with audio controls, this didn't work for me. Pressing any of the buttons gives you the "alert sound", which I assume indicates you can't do that action from the lock screen.

Comment: I updated my suggestion with feedback for a newer macOS version